# Symfony Doctrine how to sort by admin generator virtual columns

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/12

The section "Virtual" columns details how to add columns to lists that belong to related models.

For example, I have 2 model classes: `Company` and `User`. A User is always a member of a Company.

For the User list I want to show the Company name, I can do this by adding a getter to the User class `getCompanyName()` and then in my generator.yml for the User module I would use the field name `company_name`.

This works and displays the Company name for each User, but how can I sort the list by using the Company name?

Comment: Do you have the relationship properly set in your schema.yml? Because if you do by building filters it would automatically add this field.

Comment: My User has a one-to-one relationship set, my Company does not have a User relation. I can call $user->getCompany() but would never need to call $company->getUser() (this would need to be multiple users anyway)

I would like to filter by Company as well as sorting by company.

In the documentation there is a function called `addSortCriteria()` but I think this has to be used with Propel and not Doctrine

Comment: Try to add the relationship beetween Company and User. I think that will tell symfony to add that filter in user. I'm always defining both relationships and, by now, it never failed.

Comment: But even if I add that, the sorting still won't work. The admin generated actions class checks that the sort field is valid column for the User table, and of course company_name is no column. I can add a CompanyName getter like I said above, but not sure how to tie it all together. I really need to be able to sort the Users list by their Company, and filter by Company too

Comment: Can you post the company and user model of your schema.yml? If you have and company_id in your user model you have to be able to sort by company. If it shows only the ids it can be change for showing name by changing the company model.

Comment: I got it working, but it shows me the company id, and I can sort by that... but is there anyway I can use the __toString method so it shows the company name instead of the id?

Comment: Yes, change el __toString() method of the company model and it will show you the name.

Comment: Sorry to continue this, thanks for your help so far. But it is my understanding that the list will be using `User::getCompanyId()` to display the information under the "Company" column. It won't be using the `Company::__toString()` method (which already returns the Company name). So my problem is getting the list to use either `User::getCompany()->__toString()` or `User::getCompany()->getCompanyName()` instead of `$user->getCompanyId()`

Comment: If I edit the file `_list_tb_tabular.php` for the User module, I can echo the Company Name instead of the Company Id. But my problem is that I'll still be sorting by Id and not by Name. So I could have the list ordered descending by Id but the names won't be in alphabetical order

Comment: You can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023247/how-to-sort-own-columns-in-admin-panel-with-symfony

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by adding a table_method, then when I implement the table method in the model, I innerjoin Company and order by a field in company. Not sure if this can be extended to sorting columns in the generated screens, but I think this works as well.