# How to sort own columns in admin panel with symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

M schema.yml:

```
News:
  columns:
    title:
      type: string(50)
    category_id:
      type: integer(4)
  relations:
    Category:
      local: category_id
      foreign: category_id
      type: one

Category:
  columns:
    category_name:
      type: string(50)

generator:
  class: sfDoctrineGenerator
  param:
    model_class:           News
    theme:                 admin
    non_verbose_templates: true
    with_show:             false
    singular:              ~
    plural:                ~
    route_prefix:          news
    with_doctrine_route:   true
    actions_base_class:    sfActions

    config:
      actions: ~
      fields:  ~
      list:
        display: [news_id, title, category_name]
      filter:
        display: [news_id, title, category_id]
      form:    ~
      edit:    ~
      new:     ~
```

In news.class:

```
public function getCategoryName()
{
  return $this->getCategories()->getCategoryName();
}
```

This works, but I can't sort this field. I can sort by id, title, category_id, but not by category_name. How can I sort by this custom column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are the steps to achieve the required result.

1. Define a table method in your generator.yml

   ```
   config:
     actions: ~
     fields:  ~
     list:
       display: [news_id, title, category_name]
       table_method: doSelectJoinCategory
   ```
2. Add doSelectJoinCateory to your NewsTable.class.php

   ```
   class NewsTable extends Doctrine_Table
   {
     ...  
     public static function doSelectJoinCategory($query)
     {
       return $query->select('r.*, c.cateogry_name')
         ->leftJoin('r.Category c');
     }
   }
   ```
3. You need to override the sort query in your actions.class.php

   ```
   class newsActions extends autoNewsActions
   {
     ...
     protected function addSortQuery($query)
     {
       if (array(null, null) == ($sort = $this->getSort()))
       {
         return;
       }

       if (!in_array(strtolower($sort[1]), array('asc', 'desc')))
       {
         $sort[1] = 'asc';
       }

       switch ($sort[0]) {
         case 'category_name':
         $sort[0] = 'c.category_name';
         break;
       }

     $query->addOrderBy($sort[0] . ' ' . $sort[1]);
   }
   ```
4. The default generator theme will require that you override the isValidSortColumn in actions.class.php

   ```
   protected function isValidSortColumn($column)
   {
     return Doctrine_Core::getTable(‘Payment’)->hasColumn($column) || $column == ‘cateogry_name’;
   }
   ```
5. You will need to override the generator theme to display sort link and icons as it requires the sort field to be real database mapped field. edit your symfony_dir/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/data/generator/sfDoctrineModule/admin/template/templates/_list_th_tabular.php :

Change this line

```
<?php if ($field->isReal()): ?>
```

To this :

```
<?php if ($field->isReal() || $field->getConfig('sortBy')): ?>
```

Hope that helps you

Comment: In the `fields` section of your `generator.yml` you can define that a field should be treated as real: `category_name: {is_real: true}` so you don't have to edit the template. Also, the `isValidSortColumn()` could be using reference to the parent function so there's no need to use the actual table name (which can change overtime).

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are trying to view a column named `category_name` and you don't have a `getCategory_Name()` method, the solution is very simple. Display the `categoryname` column not `category_name`.

```yml
config:
  actions: ~
  fields:  ~
  list:
    display: [news_id, title, categoryname]
    table_method: doSelectJoinCategory
  filter:
    display: [news_id, title, category_id]
  form:    ~
  edit:    ~
  new:     ~
```

```php
public function getCategoryName()
{
  return $this->getCategories()->getCategoryName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a interested article explaining how to sort all virtual columns(foreign fields).

http://sakrawebstudio.blogspot.com/2011/01/sort-by-foreign-key-or-custom-column-in.html